# angular 7 How to reduce production build size

Tags: angular, angular7, xlsx, pdf.js, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

How to reduce production build size.

production build : ng build --prod

angular.json config file:

[image]

[image]

[image]

main.js(4.3mB) has pdf.js(303kB), pdf_viewer.js(100kB)
apart from these a seperate pdf.worker.js(739kB) is also present.

cpexcel.js and xlsx.js are taking more space.

i never used jszip present in xlsx

Iam using ng2-pdf-viewer to work with pdf files.

---

Dev build: ng build

[image]

here main.js(1.2mb) does not contain  pdf.js(303kB), pdf_viewer.js(100kB). These are included in vendor.js.

But has pdfworker.js of size 1.51mB

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar issu, for my solution: You can intall [custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) to your `devDependencies`

Read their doc to see how to use this package, there is my confituration `extrat-webpack.config.js` of  to remove cpexcel and jszip

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: { 
            "./dist/cpexcel.js": "",
            "./jszip.js": ""
        }
    },
};
```

By the way, I'm using `angular 9` and `"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^10.0.0",`